# Add Images On Top Of A Background Image using PHP

Tags: php, image

I Have A Background Image Now I want PHP to Put Another Image On Top Of It (The Other Image Is Stored in A Variable)
Example variable $x
& My Background Image Is Also A Variable $back
Example ../img/back.jpg
Now i wish to Add The $x On The Left side of The Background
How May I Achieve this?
Like In This Pic There is The Green Part with a Shadow Image
How Can I replace that PART with another Picture using PHP?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjK0o.jpg)
What i Have so Far
     https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOKID/picture?width=9999&height=9999", "picture.jpg");
    $x =  "picture.jpg";
    $back = "bg.jpg";
    ?>

Comment: You should consider reading the [ask] guide before posting a question. Also you need to post some code you have.

Comment: Please post your code .